# Save login attempts and open drawer only on first login attempt with react and redux

Tags: reactjs, cookies, redux, react-redux, local-storage

I have a site where I would like a drawer/modal to open only the first time the user is logged in. What is a good way to do this? I am thinking maybe some sort of login counter, but I am not sure how to save the result or where. Maybe local-storage or a cookie?

I use React and Redux but I am pretty new to both/have been using both a few months.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of three solutions:

- client-side: you store the login counter value into the user's browser, either with a cookie or localStorage. But obviously this will not work cross-browser or in incognito mode
- server-side: you store the login counter in your server's database. It requires more work because you need to code the client-server logic, and it only works if the user is online (not warranted with a PWA)
- with your authentication provider: I surmise some third party auth provider can store the last login timestamp, which you can use to detect if it is a first login

As for redux, the state is not persisted by default: it is reset on every page refresh or browser restart. You need to use an additional library to persist your store, for example [redux-persist](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-persist)

Comment: That's awesome! Thank you for a very well-elaborated and thorough answer! I will mark this as the right answer. I have a timestamp from the authentication provider so maybe I can do something with that? Did you have an idea in mind? Like storing and comparing the date or something? I have also thought about the localstorage or cookie issue with incognito but I'm not sure if that's overthinking it. Server-side is not possible unfortunately. Thanks again!

Comment: I'm glad it helped you. Good if you can use metadata from the auth provider: this is the most robust and requires the least amount of code. Now you need to detect whether it is the first login, for this you must delve into your auth provider's documentation to see what they provide: is the timestamp undefined on first login? or is it equal to current time? etc... The use this info for rendering your component conditionally, there are several techniques: https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html

Comment: Hi again! I see. Yes, the login timestamp is equal to the time of login, also on the first login which happens a few seconds after the user-registration is finished (depending on users internet speed etc.). They also have a timestamp for when the registration is done, so they differ by a few seconds.

Comment: Sounds good: now you only have to compare the registration timestamp to the last login and if the difference is smaller than some threshold, it means this is a first login. Happy coding!